# Mysql server is down on XAMPP and the log shows me no error

Tags: xampp

For a few minutes Mysql server was working, then when I closed the control panel and opened it up again it would just say:
Error mysql shutdown unexpectedly on the control panel but no error is presented on the logs from mysql_error.logs.

This is whats in the logs:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 47160; transaction id 8
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201231  3:42:47
2020-12-31  3:42:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

P.S: I can still access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ (if that's relevant at all to my problem)

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you reinstall XAMPP. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to mysql/data folder
2. remove all master-X.info files and
   multi-master.info file
3. restart apache and mysql

check if it is solved or not